# Extracting feature from the last layer before classification in keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, theano, tensorflow

I have tried to extract feature in the keras ( with tensorflow and as well as with theano background). But became not successful.

My code is :

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, input_shape=(3,img_width, img_height)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=.01))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Convolution2D(64, 2, 2))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=.01))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(8))

model.add(ActivityRegularization(l2=0.01))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

 model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)


test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode='binary')



scores = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, 237)
print("Accuracy = ", scores[1])
```

I have used fit_generator for train, validation and test cases.

My code for getting output from e.g., layer 3  was:

```
get_activations = theano.function([model.layers[0].input], 
model.layers[3].output(train=False), allow_input_downcast=True)

activations = get_activations(test_generator)
```

But after excuting it I am getting an error :

```
 File "test.py", line 96, in <module>
 get_activations = theano.function([model.layers[0].input], 
 model.layers[3].output(train=False), allow_input_downcast=True)
 TypeError: 'TensorVariable' object is not callable
```

How can I do it In theano or in the tensorflow mode ( any of them or both). I have used fit_generator in my code for image augmentation.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I recommend you to switch to Keras-2.x for a better experience. Keras-2.x is more well-organized.

Secondly, using theano codes like `theano.function` is not recommended, you should use `keras.backend.function` instead.

The error is raised because `model.layers[3].output` is a tensor, you cannot call a tensor like `model.layers[3].output(train=False)`.

My code to extract features usually looks like:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, input_shape=(3,img_width, img_height)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 2, 2))

# blablabla...

model.add(Dense(8, name='feature'))

model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

feature_network = Model(model.input, model.get_layer('feature').output)
feature = feature_network.predict(your_data_here)
```

I use `feature` to name the target feature layer and use the `get_layer` function to retrieve that layer.

Comment: thanks a lot ..... it works for theano background.. but not for tensorflow though...

Comment: hey.... it was error generating by the numpy while trying to save the feature array... i solved it. thanks...

Comment: not a prob. If you find Keras code works with Theano but not Tensorflow, you can submit a issue on github.